# Applying pandas cut to grouped items where bin depends on column value

Tags: pandas

Following on from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760555/575530), I would like to apply cut with varying bin size, to a grouped table. For example, I would like to turn this

```
+------+--------+--------+
| User | Value1 | Value2 |
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |     56 |     12 |
|    1 |     28 |     30 |
|    1 |     65 |     42 |
|    2 |    394 |     33 |
|    2 |      2 |     43 |
|    2 |     60 |     45 |
|    3 |      5 |     20 |
|    3 |      5 |     80 |
+------+--------+--------+
```

into this

```
+------+--------+--------+-----------+
| User | Value1 | Value2 |  Interval |
+------+--------+--------+-----------+
|    1 |     56 |     12 |           |
|    1 |     28 |     30 | (12, 30]  |
|    1 |     65 |     42 | (30, 42]  |
|    2 |    394 |     33 |           |
|    2 |      2 |     43 | (33, 43]  |
|    2 |     60 |     45 | (43, 45]  |
|    3 |      5 |     20 |           |
|    3 |      5 |     80 | (20, 80]  |
+------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42265928/575530) to the question 'applying pandas cut within a groupby' my attempt so far is

```python
import pandas

data = {
    'User': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'Value1': [56, 28, 65, 394, 2, 60, 5, 5],
    'Value2': [12, 30, 42, 33, 43, 45, 20, 80]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['Interval'] = df.groupby(['User']).transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x['Value2'], bins=x['Value2']))
```

but this gives the error

> KeyError: ('Value2', 'occurred at index Value1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `apply` with `cut`

```
df['Interval'] = df.groupby('User').Value2.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=x))

Out[1997]:
   User  Value1  Value2      Interval
0     1      56      12           NaN
1     1      28      30  (12.0, 30.0]
2     1      65      42  (30.0, 42.0]
3     2     394      33           NaN
4     2       2      43  (33.0, 43.0]
5     2      60      45  (43.0, 45.0]
6     3       5      20           NaN
7     3       5      80  (20.0, 80.0]
```

---

If you prefer `transform`, it still works as follows

```
df['Interval'] = df.groupby('User').Value2.transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=x))

Out[2000]:
   User  Value1  Value2      Interval
0     1      56      12           NaN
1     1      28      30  (12.0, 30.0]
2     1      65      42  (30.0, 42.0]
3     2     394      33           NaN
4     2       2      43  (33.0, 43.0]
5     2      60      45  (43.0, 45.0]
6     3       5      20           NaN
7     3       5      80  (20.0, 80.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am confused as to why `df.groupby(['User'])['Value2'].apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=x))` works but `df.groupby(['User']).apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x['Value2'], bins=x['Value2']))` fails, they look like they should do the same thing to me

Comment: @dumbledad: One is called `apply` on `SeriesGroupby` and the other is called on `DataFrameGroupby`. Both return the same output bins. However, the result of `SeriesGroupby` is single level index, while `DataFrameGroupby` is multi-level index. Therefore, `DataFrameGroupby` is failed when assigning the result back to `df` due to different/incompatble index.